# Different behavior for value attribute in lightning:inputField for lookup field

Tags: lightning-inputfield

I have a requirement where user needs to create a new Opportunity record in a lightning popup.Here I have to display a Territory field which is a lookup .So I am using `lightning:inputField` tag for this within `lightning:recordEditForm`.

```
 <lightning:inputField aura:id="Territory" fieldName="Territory__c" required="true"/>
```

But now user wants to have a default territory to be shown on initial loading. If they dont want the default territory, they can change that value. So in order to show default value I have added value field in `lightning:inputField`

```
 <lightning:inputField aura:id="Territory" fieldName="Territory__c" value="{!v.defaultTerritory}" required="true"/>
```

defaultTerritory --> Assigning it from backend on loading.

Now if I try to save the Opportunity with default territory, the JSON record passed from lightning to apex is

```
{"sobjectType":"Opportunity","Name":"Jan 2201-1","AccountId":"00X0j00000KGXXXXXX","Territory__c":"a0X0j000000nXXXXXX","CurrencyIsoCode":"JPY","OwnerId":"00Xf100000HIuXXXX"}
```

If I change from default territory to new territory in lookup , on saving the JSON record passed is,

```
{"sobjectType":"Opportunity","Name":"Jan 2201-1","AccountId":"00X0j00000KGXXXXXX","Territory__c":["a0X0j000000nXXXXXX"],"CurrencyIsoCode":"JPY","OwnerId":"00Xf100000HIuXXXX"}
```

The territory Id is enclosed within a square bracket[].

Could anyone please let me know what is the mistake I am doing.Why [] is getting added while changing territory and how to resolve it.

Comment: Whats data type of `v.defaultTerritory` ?

Comment: How is your `save` function implemented?

Comment: v.defaultTerritory is a String which stores the Id of the Territory

Comment: I am passing the entire Opportunity record from Lightning component to apex class.In save method, i am inserting this Opportunity using Database.insert

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got the workaround to resolve the issue.

But still, let me give the workaround and it would help others

- If you change from default value to new value in lookup, the value will be assigned as a list in JSON i.e, "Territory__c":["a0X0j000000nXXXXXX"] enclosed within a square bracket[].

I would suggest before assigning value typecast it to a string and assign to JSON in your JS controller. i.e, 
var Territory = component.get("v.defaultTerritory");
Territory = event.getParam('value').toString();
component.set("v.defaultTerritory", Territory);

Thanks,
Kumbresh

Answer (score -1):

Instead of assigning the value using attribute, I am directly assigning using
component.find("v.Name","TerritoryId") and it is working fine.